# Nikon D70 and Sigma EF-500 DG Super NA-iTTL Flash

Tags: flash, sigma, nikon-d70

I have a D70 and Sigma flash gun, which I understand should work with the camera. I have read it is important to have the iTTL versions of the flash gun for it to be able to work with the iTTL metering of the D70.

However the camera and flash don't seem to be "talking" to each other and any pictures taken are just white.

Can anyone tell me how to get them working together?

I'm currently using a Nikkor 18-200 VR lens and the flash is supposed to zoom with the lens, which mine also does not. I'm not sure if the flash/lens combination are incompatible but I would have thought the camera-flash and camera-lens compatibility are more significant.

I'd hoped I would be able to attach the flash and just shoot away, but I wonder if there are settings I need to change in the camera to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on when the flash was sold, its firmware may be incompatible with the camera. Sigma reverse-engineers the flash protocol, so incompatibility with new models is common. Usually, a firmware update fixes this — but unfortunately (unlike with higher-end Metz flashes, which have a USB port) this needs to be done by Sigma. They usually do this for free, but I'm not sure if they will for a model this old, especially if you are not the original owner. Best bet is to call and find out.